# MySQL - Best way to back up data older than 90 days

Tags: mysql, database, google-bigquery, database-backups

We have a big MySQL database(~400 GB).

Currently, we have historical data from more than 2 years ago.

Currently, we are planning to maintain only the last 90 days of data here on in our main DB and periodically move the old data out.

For now, we are considering to move data to Google Big Query as it's a cheaper option.

In case when a customer requests some old data(not a frequent case), we are planning to serve the data from Big Query.

I want to know if there is any better way/ technologies to do this?

Comment: This is off topic, since it's going to get highly opinionated answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Pentium10 , done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data size is not huge. BigQuery supports up to petabyte scale. Also supports importing files up to 5 TB.

We have implemented your use case. 
We periodically backup our MySql db to BigQuery.

1. mysql console, SELECT INTO FILE syntax to produce a csv or tsv. You may need to replace invalid chars.
2. upload to google cloud
3. issue a BQ import command from GCS into BigQuery (you can use predefined schema or autoschema)

In time, the first and second steps are taking the longest, around 20 minutes. Importing in BigQuery is like 30 seconds to 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks @Pentium10 for your insights, just wanted to know if you have again used the data from BigQuery to serve requests. How was the performance of this scenario if you have used?

Comment: We do not serve to the end user nothing from BigQuery, as it's warehouse so it responds with over 600ms, average query is 1-2 seconds though. So we run in background jobs queries to BigQuery and cache that and we server from cache to end user. This way we don't add latency to the requests.

Comment: Ok got it, Thanks.